# 'Date' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: swift, xcode

Date' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
1. Found this candidate (Foundation.Date)
2. Found this candidate (DocuSignESign.Date)

```
extension Date {
    func isGreaterThanDate(_ dateToCompare: Date) -> Bool {

         // Do some stuff here

    }
}
```

I understand that Xcode is complaining that the Date extension I have declared is not clear and does not know which one I am referring two among the two. But what I don't know is how to solve this issue. Any leads will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Why would a 3rd party library define their own `Date` class in Swift? That's just asking for problems.

Comment: Agreed but that's how it is...

Comment: Just specify the module name, such as `Foundation.Date` or `DocuSignESign.Date` which ever you want to use. That should solve the problem.

Comment: See these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=is%20ambiguous%20for%20type%20lookup%20in%20this%20context) on the error and you will find plenty of solutions.