# Ambiguous Reference in Swift

Tags: swift, ambiguous-call

I reference two frameworks [PDFGenerator and PDFKit] that both contain an object named PDFPage.  In the PDFGenerator framework, PDFPage is an Enum.  In the PDFKit framework, PDFPage is an object.  When I try to create an instance of the PDFPage Enum I get the error:

> 'PDFPage' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context'.

How do I specify which PDFPage I am trying to instantiate?

Simplified example below:

```
import PDFKit

import PDFGenerator

public class VC: UIViewController {
    var page:PDFPage? // <-- This throws the error mentioned above.
}
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+is+ambiguous+for+type+lookup+in+this+context)

Comment: you need to called its init method to solve issue using let page = PDFPage()

Comment: Have you tried `PDFKit.PDFPage` or `PDFGenerator.PDFPage` ?

Comment: As per this article [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952394/date-is-ambiguous-for-type-lookup-in-this-context], var page:PDFGenerator.PDFPage should be the answer.  The reason this does not work in my example is because in the 'PDFGenerator' framework there is a public class also named 'PDFGenerator'.  When I try to declare my variable as page:PDFGenerator.PDFPage it results in the error 'PDFPage' is not a member type of 'PDFGenerator'.  Naming a class within a framework the same name as the framework itself may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it will solve error.**

```
import PDFKit
import PDFGenerator

public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let page = PDFPage() // <-- This solve the error mentioned above.

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This compiles but does not solve my specific need to declare the variable as PDFKit.PDFPage.